# Intellij - when the folder structure is different than the package name

Tags: java, intellij-idea, package

My package name does not contain my full folder structure.
For instance - in IntelliJ I have created a test class:

[image: hierarchy]

and its package was initialized with `package com;`

1. How do I set which is the starting folder for the package name?
2. What is the difference between blue and yellow/gold folder color in the IntelliJ project window?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> How do I set which isw the starting folder for the package name

File -> Project Structure. On the left, select Modules.

In the rightmost window, you will have a tab named "Sources". There you will have the opportunity to change your source/test directories. Note that a directory must exist before it is selectable this way.

Although I wouldn't depart from the setup you currently have, it's pretty standard.

> What is the difference between blue and yellow/gold folder color in intelliJ project window

You will see that in the tab above ;)